# How to make react stop duplicating elements on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, for-loop, google-cloud-firestore

The problem is that every time I click on an element with a state things appear twice. For example if i click on a button and the result of clicking would be to output something in the console, it would output 2 times. However in this case, whenever I click a function is executed twice.

The code:

```
const getfiles = async () => {
    let a = await documentSpecifics;

    for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        var wrt = document.querySelectorAll("#writeto");
        var fd = document.querySelector('.filtered-docs');
        var newResultEl = document.createElement('div');
        var writeToEl = document.createElement('p');
        newResultEl.classList.add("result");
        writeToEl.id = "writeto";
        newResultEl.appendChild(writeToEl);
        fd.appendChild(newResultEl);
        listOfNodes.push(writeToEl);
        listOfContainers.push(newResultEl);
        wrt[i].textContent = a[i].data.documentName;                        
     }
}
```

The code here is supposed to create a new div element with a paragraph tag and getting data from firebase firestore, will write to the p tag the data. Now if there are for example 9 documents in firestore and i click a button then 9 more divs will be replicated. Now in total there are 18 divs and only 9 containing actual data while the rest are just blank. It continues to create 9 more divs every click.
I'm also aware of `React.Strictmode` doing this for some debugging but I made sure to take it out and still got the same results.
Firebase code:

```
//put data in firebase
createFileToDb = () => {
        var docName = document.getElementById("title-custom").value; //get values
        var specifiedWidth = document.getElementById("doc-width").value;
        var specifiedHeight = document.getElementById("doc-height").value;
        var colorType = document.getElementById("select-color").value;

        parseInt(specifiedWidth); //transform strings to integers
        parseInt(specifiedHeight);
        
        firebase.firestore().collection("documents")
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .collection("userDocs")
        .add({
            documentName: docName,
            width: Number(specifiedWidth), //firebase-firestore method for converting the type of value in the firestore databse
            height: Number(specifiedHeight),
            docColorType: colorType,
            creation: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() // it is possible that this is necessary in order to use "orderBy" when getting data
        }).then(() => {
            console.log("file in database");
        }).catch(() => {
            console.log("failed");
        })
    }

//get data
GetData = () => {
        return firebase.firestore()
        .collection("documents")
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .collection("userDocs")
        .orderBy("creation", "asc")
        .get()
        .then((doc) => {
            let custom = doc.docs.map((document) => {
                var data = document.data();
                var id = document.id;
                return { id, data }
            })
            return custom;
            
        }).catch((err) => {console.error(err)});

    }

waitForData = async () => {
        let result = await this.GetData();
        return result;
}
//in render
let documentSpecifics = this.waitForData().then((response) => response)
        .then((u) => {
            if(u.length > 0) {
                for(let i = 0; i < u.length; i++) {
                    try {
                        //
                    } catch(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                }
                
            }
            return u;
        });
```

Edit: firebase auth is functioning fine so i dont think it has anything to do with the problem
Edit: This is all in a class component
Edit: Clicking a button calls the function `createFileToDb`

Comment: None of the code you shared shows an interaction with Firebase. If the interaction with Firebase is necessary to reproduce the problem, show the code for that please. If you can reproduce the problem without Firebase, please don't tag it with those tags. I also recommend studying [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it really helps if you isolate the problem.

Comment: Also, if you're using [tag:reactjs], you probably shouldn't be using DOM methods like `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: changing to other methods of getting these elements didnt really help. I used `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementById` but it did not change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that i found the answer to my problem.
Basically, since this is a class component I took things out of the render and put some `console.log` statements to see what was happening. what i noticed is that it logs twice in render but not outside of it. So i took the functions out.
Here is the code that seems to fix my issue:

```
contain = () => {
        const documentSpecifics = this.waitForData().then((response) => {
            var wrt = document.getElementsByClassName('writeto');
            for(let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                this.setNewFile();
                wrt[i].textContent = response[i].data.documentName;
            }

            return response;
        })
        this.setState({
            docs: documentSpecifics,
            docDisplayType: !this.state.docDisplayType
        })
    }
```

As for creating elements i put them in a function so i coud reuse it:

```
setNewFile = () => {
        const wrt = document.querySelector(".writeto");
        const fd = document.querySelector("#filtered-docs");
        var newResultEl = document.createElement('div');
        newResultEl.classList.add("result");
        var wrtEl = document.createElement('p');
        wrtEl.classList.add("writeto");
        fd.appendChild(newResultEl);
        newResultEl.appendChild(wrtEl);
    }
```

The firebase and firestore code remains the same.
the functions are called through elements in the return using onClick.